# Is there any inequality for the expectation of minimization of a random variable of Markov chain?

Tags: inequality, markov-chains

Let $X^i_1,X^i_2,\ldots,X^i_n$ be independent stationary Markov chains on a same space $\Omega = \{s_1,\ldots,s_m\}$ with a same transition matrix $P$ and $X^i_1\sim \pi$ for
$i=1,2,\ldots,N$ ($N>m$).

I would like to find a **lower** bound of the following random variable:

$$f(\{X^i_j\}_{i=1}^N):= E_\pi[\min_{s\in\Omega}\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb{1}(X^i_j=s)],$$
where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of $\{X^i_j\}$ and $\mathbb{1}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

Is there any useful inequality?

Comment: $P(X_j=s)=\pi_s$ which is fixed and not random. You just pick out the state with the minimal stationary probability. Seems like there must be some missing context here, or a typo. Of course I could also be misunderstanding...

Comment: True! I made a mistake.
I revised the typo.

Comment: The indicator function will always be zero for some $s$, so the expected value is zero. What am I misunderstanding? Does this question have a source (textbook, class assignment, etc.) or some broader context that would make understanding it easier?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I made a mistake in trying to simplify the original problem. I originally wanted to consider the sum of independent Markov chain obeying the same space and distribution.

Comment: If you edit your question to reflect that with careful attention to detail, someone here might be able to help. I can try helping decipher it too if course.